# Comparing 2 files containing IP addresses and returning one's that are not common

Tags: python-3.x

This is what I have done so far:

```
import difflib

with open('node_list.txt', 'r') as f1, open('aws_instances_dnsname.txt', 'r') as f2:
    diff = difflib.ndiff(f1.readlines(), f2.readlines())
    with open('diff.txt', 'w') as result:
        for line in diff:
            result.write(line)
```

Comment: Could you include the expected output and the actual output? That would greatly help our efforts to help you.

Comment: What you are trying is too complicated. Maybe is better just to load the second text file in a string or string list, then iterate lines only of 'node_list.txt' and just check if the IPs from the first file 'node_list.txt' are contained in the string with python string.find(), but only remove "\n" and "\r" symbols. I have done this but in C.

Comment: The result I got is mostly repeating the whole list of file1, so there's something I am missing with finding the difference

Comment: You could put `set()` around your ips and then getting the difference that way. This means you wouldn't need `difflib`.

Comment: @GeeTransit maybe I should try that.

Comment: I used a library and avoided the problem altogether

Answer (score 0):

If your files were like this:

File 1:
apple
banana
kokonut
orange

File 2:
banana
strawberry
orange
lime

You could try something like this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    read_first = set()
    read_second = set()
    while True:
        line = f1.readline().strip()
        if line == '':
            break
        read_first.add(line)
    # end while
    while True:
        line = f2.readline().strip()
        if line == '':
            break
        read_second.add(line)
    # end while
    first = set()
    second = set()
    for i, j in zip(read_first, read_second):
        first.add(i.strip())
        second.add(j.strip())
    diff = first - second # set difference (items in first not in second)
    with open('diff.txt', 'w') as result:
        for item in diff:
            result.write(item + '\n')
```

This would output into `diff.txt` and would display:
apple
kokonut

Note how banana and orange don't appear on the file we've created.

Comment: Actually, this is just concatenating the 2 lists into a single file

Comment: Okay. I've fixed it so it doesn't test with the `\n`s on the end. If it's not working for you, could you post a sample of the error output or the traceback? Thanks.

Comment: It is working but it is just returning both the files in diff.txt

Comment: Did you want only one of the files to be checked?

Comment: file a = ip-10-232-10-149 ip-10-232-10-150 ip-10-232-10-151 ip-10-232-10-152
file b = ip-10-232-10-149 ip-10-232-10-152

I want only ip-10-232-10-150 ip-10-232-10-151

Comment: whatever is common in file2 shouldn't appear in the new file

Comment: I've changed it so it should work now. Instead of it getting the symmetric difference, it's now just the difference from first file and second file.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to attach the files? that should help probably

Comment: What do you mean by 'attach'?

Comment: Actually, the script is not reading through all the lines, it is only going through stuff partially

Comment: I think it kind of fails as it adds an item to the set if it's the same, but that shouldn't matter. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Not sure but it is just iterating through some lines and only giving partial output

Comment: Could you give some example input and example output?

Comment: f1 = 
datacube-2
fileserver
ip-10-232-10-148
ip-10-232-10-149
ip-10-232-10-155
ip-10-232-10-157
ip-10-232-10-185
ip-10-232-10-201
ip-10-232-10-224
ip-10-232-10-228

f2=
ip-10-232-9-114
ip-10-232-8-254
ip-10-232-113-202
ip-10-232-25-73
ip-10-232-0-150
ip-10-232-18-18
ip-10-232-10-70
ip-10-232-105-237
ip-10-232-19-87
ip-10-232-105-223

Comment: output is only going through things partially and just giving me those as output

Comment: I'm going to change the answer to use `.readline()` instead of `.readlines()` as that might be because of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are sorted or otherwise deterministically-ordered:

```
diff --old-line-format='' --new-line-format='' --unchanged-line-format='%L' file1.txt file2.txt
```

For sufficiently-large files, the one-shot cost of starting a subprocess will be smaller than the cost of doing logic in python.

Example using `subprocess` module (note that `diff` is expected to return `1`, so we can't just use `check_call`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess


INPUT1 = 'file1.txt'
INPUT2 = 'file2.txt'
OUTPUT = 'common.txt'

with open(OUTPUT, 'wb') as out:
    cmd = ['diff', '--old-line-format=', '--new-line-format=', '--unchanged-line-format=%L', INPUT1, INPUT2]
    rv = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=out)
    if rv >= 2:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(rv, cmd)
```

Comment: I didn't get the answer